# Weighted randomness based on current values (Not sure how else to explain it)

Tags: java, random, probability, weighted

Need some help with some code (Java)

I have a script which runs every few mins
This script creates and deletes objects

For the sake of this example I want to have an average of 10 objects at any time

But a random probability of it creating and deleting objects based on how far it is from that 10 goal with hard limits, eg +- 3

I have gotten it to create objects till it reaches 7, and then delete once it goes past 13
But I cant figure out how to do the randomness between

If there is say 8 objects then it would have a higher probability of creating rather than deleting, if there are 10 then its a 50/50 split
and if there is 12 then its more likely to delete then create

and im not asking for code, im happy to figure that out myself
I just need a push in the right direction

Edit for update with what I currently have, I dont have the full code as there is alot of other things going on, but this is the part i need help with

This runs every min

```
int limit = F_Config.get().getInt("Limit");
int avg = F_Config.get().getInt("Average");
int current = P_Player.ReturnList().size();
int min = avg - limit;
int max = avg + limit;

//below min
if(current < min) {
    Main.sendConsole("Min");
    P_Player.LoginPlayer();
}

//above Max
else if(current > max) {
    Main.sendConsole("Max");
    P_Player.LogoutPlayer();
}

//Between min and Max
else{
    //Stuff here
}
```

Comment: Show what you have so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to clarify the algorithm, after how to implement (java) is something else.

There are 2 operations : [add] and [delete] and you have to define based on some criteria the probability.

Say:
[Objects,AddP,DeleteP]

1. [0,1,0] -> only option is to add
2. [1 up to n, a, 1-a] , eg: [1-9, 0.75, 0.25]
3. [n+1, m, b, 1-b] , eg: [10-15. 0.3, 0.7]
4. [m+1, 0, 1] , eg: [16, 0, 1] -> only option is to delete

On [2] and [3] just generate a random number and compare with a,b probability and choose an operation.
Eg: [2] random = 0.60<0.75 => add, etc

Note: 0 < a < 1 (same with b)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Prob 
{
    List<PSet> l = new ArrayList<PSet>();
    List<MyObj> obj = new ArrayList<MyObj>();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Prob p = new Prob();
        PSet ps1 = p.new PSet(0,0,1,0);
        PSet ps2 = p.new PSet(1,3,0.8,0.2);
        PSet ps3 = p.new PSet(4,5,0.3,0.7);
        PSet ps4 = p.new PSet(6,6,0,1);
        p.l.add(ps1);
        p.l.add(ps2);
        p.l.add(ps3);
        p.l.add(ps4);

        //loop 20 times
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            int counter = p.obj.size();
            for(int j=0;j<p.l.size();j++)
            {
                PSet ps = p.l.get(j);
                if(counter == 0 && counter == ps.start)
                {
                    System.out.println(i+"_only_add, counter="+counter);
                    p.obj.add(p.new MyObj(String.valueOf(i)));

                }
                else if(counter > 0 && counter == ps.start && counter == ps.end)
                {
                    System.out.println(i+"_only_del, counter="+counter);
                    p.obj.remove(0);
                }

                else if(counter>=ps.start && counter<=ps.end)
                {
                    double rand = Math.random();
                    if(rand<ps.pAdd)
                    {
                        System.out.println(i+"_add, counter="+counter);
                        p.obj.add(p.new MyObj(String.valueOf(i)));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println(i+"_del, counter="+counter);
                        p.obj.remove(0);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    class MyObj
    {
        String name;
        MyObj(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
    class PSet
    {
        public int getStart() {
            return start;
        }
        public int getEnd() {
            return end;
        }
        public double getpAdd() {
            return pAdd;
        }
        public double getpDel() {
            return pDel;
        }
        int start;
        int end;
        double pAdd;
        double pDel;
        PSet(int start, int end, double pAdd, double pDel)
        {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.pAdd = pAdd;
            this.pDel = pDel;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0_only_add, counter=0
1_add, counter=1
2_add, counter=2
3_add, counter=3
4_del, counter=4
5_add, counter=3
6_del, counter=4
7_add, counter=3
8_del, counter=4
9_add, counter=3
10_del, counter=4
11_add, counter=3
12_del, counter=4
13_add, counter=3
14_add, counter=4
15_add, counter=5
16_only_del, counter=6
17_del, counter=5
18_del, counter=4
19_del, counter=3
```

Comment: That seems to be more of a set probability rather than dynamic
EG anything below the average has the same chance, where i want it to change based on how far from center it gets.

But it might have given me some ideas of where to go

Comment: Ended up using the ideas you had given and based on that, I took the minimum and maximum, calculated the percentage of where the current was in relation to that range, generated a random number between 0 and 100 (to match percentage) and then used that to determine if I created or deleted

Comment: Updated. It's entirely up to you to set what_ever probability you wanted (can be set also dynanic a/b)